# split on char, but leave that char - python

Tags: python, string, split

I want to split a string when the specific character occurs(ex: .,! etc)
I have written the split function, it does split, but removes those characters.
When I call function for example:

```
text = 'The first line leads off, With a gap before the next. Then the poem ends.'
```

I get

```
['The first line leads off', ' With a gap before the next', ' Then the poem ends']
```

What needs to be changed so the characters will not be removed?So I will get this:

```
['The first line leads off,', ' With a gap before the next.', ' Then the poem ends.']
```

.

```
def split_on_separators(original, separators):


    word_list = [original]
    new_list = [ ]
    for given in separators:
        for word in word_list:                  
            new_list.extend(word.split(given))  

        word_list = new_list                    
        new_list = list()                       
    return word_list
```

Thank you.

Comment: My suggestion would be to not write your own function for this, there are plenty of resources you can use within python to accomplish it.  See my answer for details.  By the way, you can unaccept answers on Stackoverflow and accept better ones ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def splitOnChars(text, chars):
    answer = []
    start = 0
    for i,char in enumerate(text):
        if char in chars:
            answer.append(text[start:i+1])
            start = i+1
    answer.append(text[i+1:])
    return answer
```

Output:

```
In [41]: text = 'The first line leads off, With a gap before the next. Then the poem ends.'

In [42]: chars = ',.!'

In [43]: splitOnChars(text, chars)
Out[43]: 
['The first line leads off,',
 ' With a gap before the next.',
 ' Then the poem ends.',
 '']
```

Comment: Much cleaner than the other submissions, and probably the best way to do it without zip or re.split.  I think that there is a more pythonic way to solve this IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could forget about writing your own function for this and use re.split and zip.  re.split will leave the separator in the resulting list as the next element when you use a capture group.  It can be joined back together using two different step iterations and zip.

```
import re
mypoem = 'The first line leads off, With a gap before the next. Then the poem ends.'

junk = re.split("(,|\.)", mypoem)
poem_split = [i1 + i2 for i1, i2 in zip(junk[0::2], junk[1::2])]
```

Comment: Cool solution! The only thing that should be improved here - if `junk` contains an odd number of entries, the last entry won't be written into `poem_split`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use regular expressions:

```
import re

text = 'The first line leads off, With a gap before the next. Then the poem ends.'
print re.findall('.*?[,.!]?', text)
# ['The first line leads off,', ' With a gap before the next.', ' Then the poem ends.']
```